# I need to create a network for a call center

Tags: networking, windows, voip

I have:

- a patch panel with 24 ports.
- Windows server
- voip connection (voice over ip)

**How do I make the connection from the patch panel to the router?**

Do I need a router? If yes does it need to have certain features?

What exactly do I have to install on the windows server to make voip work?

What do I need to install on the clients to make everything work (something open source)?

Any other advice would be most appreciated. I am a newbie with this, please help.

**edit**:

They didn't give me any specifications of what software or hardware to use, I have to figure it out by myself, this is why I'm asking for help.

I am presuming my provider handles sip. Internal users are going to use soft phones. My telephone system will just need to be calling in/out.

It's really stupid that my question got closed. I just needed advice on how and what should I do from people with experience not from frustrated people who have nothing to do with the subject.

Comment: Sorry, this is WAY overbroad for a single question. You need to call someone to help you with this.

Comment: You're not qualified to undertake this kind of project without one of the following things happening. 1) Early death. 2) Being murdered by the client. 3) getting a completely useless and unmaintainable end result.  Quick answer. Don't Do It.  Find a contractor who can do it all for you, and pay them to do it.

Comment: How exactly did you get this project? Are you an employee of the company or are you a contractor?

Comment: @joeqwerty - My guess is, Lowest Bidder.

Comment: Some friend of a friend wanted to open a call center and I offered to look into the problem and help, this was my starting place.

Comment: @Andrei - you misunderstood Tom's comment, he wasn't wishing you harm, simply saying that if you start this work you're opening yourself up to negativity from your customer as it appears to be beyond your skills. I've deleted your comment as it was clearly a translation issue.

Comment: So I misunderstood the part where he said that if I were to take this kind of project i were to die early or get murdered by client? After which he tells me to seek help somewhere else? How about I start answering all the questions(or commenting them) with the same kind of attitude. "You can't do this, go find someone to do it for you." WOW that's really helpful, thanks both of you! If I ever have any intention to commit suicide or if I'm feeling depressed I know which website to come to. Seems that this is what you lot do here best.

Comment: @Andrei, if you're feeling suicidal, then call centre networking is definitely not the place to be.  Those places are soul-destroying at best.

Comment: @Andrei, do you not understand that Tom meant 'murdered' as a metaphor for "a great deal of negativity", not actual violence? And I didn't tell you to seek help elsewhere in my comment, Tom did, that said from your questions I can understand why he did. Your post was closed because at least 5 other users on the site thought it not appropriate for the site, that's how this site (which is for professionals) works.

Comment: Wow Tom, you are not giving up, it's funny but uncalled for. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Rubbish.  I'm British.  Humour and wit are a natural response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commute packets so you need a switch, you need to handle voip so your switch will need to handle Qos, you also need to acess the outside so you need a router. 
If you need to implement a IPBX then asterix may be your weapon of choice.
You're question is too broad to answer correctly. Maybe you 'll better bet on contacting a contractor for that.

Comment: "commute packets"? -- What about "Switch" packets.

Comment: Ooops! maybe my french to english translation was not that good after all.

Answer (score 6):

- let others do it.
- if you want to get a reasonable answer i suggest you add [much] more details - eg:

  - what voip protocol does your service provider handle [probably sip, but it's worth checking]
  - are your internal users going to use soft or hard-phones
  - what features should the telephone system offer - just calling in/out? call groups? auditing/recording? ivr?

open source voip for windows sounds experimental - you might consider using linux and  [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) or [freeswitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/) under it. there are few commercial voip platforms for windows - [3cx](http://www.3cx.com/) is one of them.

Comment: As far as hardware ... if you're connecting a network, your patch panel needs to be connected to a switch. If you're going send/receive calls outside your network, you'll need a router. As far as the rest ... this is a big question. What have you researched so far? I agree with pQd ... to my knowledge asterisk is one of the most common PBX systems in the world, it might be worth looking into. At the same time, a live business server is probably not the place to be learning linux if you don't know it.

Comment: This has to be done on a windows server. Also thanks plenty, this really helped!

Comment: Yes, I second this. As the systems administrator for a VoIP provider, I can definitely tell you that without the knowledge you'd need to answer the easy networking questions, you'll be hopelessly lost when tackling Asterisk. Give up now and find someone who has past experience doing this.