# I need to create a network for a call center

Tags: networking, voip, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need to create a network for a call center.](https://serverfault.com/questions/294982/i-need-to-create-a-network-for-a-call-center)

I have:

- a patch panel with 24 ports.
- Windows server
- voip connection (voice over ip)

**How do I make the connection from the patch panel to the router?**

Do I need a router? If yes does it need to have certain features?

What exactly do I have to install on the windows server to make voip work?

What do I need to install on the clients to make everything work (something open source)?

Any other advice would be most appreciated. I am a newbie with this, please help.

**edit**:

They didn't give me any specifications of what software or hardware to use, I have to figure it out by myself, this is why I'm asking for help.

I am presuming my provider handles sip. Internal users are going to use soft phones. My telephone system will just need to be calling in/out.

Answer (score 0):

If they still need internet they will need a router.
if tehy already have internet they aleady have a router.

the other questions depend on which software you want to use.
did whoever needs the call center say anyting about whjat they want, or did they just say we want a call center?

look here for now: [wiki sip software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software)